# Mac OS X: upgrading from pip 18.1 to pip 19.1 changed python versions - how to change back?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, pip

I upgraded from pip 18.1 to 19.1 and it changed my python version. I was using python 3.6 before the upgrade, and now it's using python 2.7. How can I switch it back?

I'm on Mac OS X High Sierra 10.13.6.

Before pip upgrade:

```
slantalpha:Giraffe user$ pip --version
pipip 18.1 from 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

After pip upgrade (in same terminal window):

```
slantalpha:Giraffe user$ pip --version
-bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

After pip upgrade (in a new terminal window):

```
slantalpha:~ user$ pip --version
pip 19.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Comment: Does `pip3` work?

Comment: Also, IMHO, it's no good to mess with system Python on macOS. Use something like [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) instead.

Answer (score 0):

`pip` is mapped to Python2. Use the `pip3` command.